# Protect element inline style

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, mutation-observers

I'm trying to protect an iframe element inline style with MutationObserver by listening for style attribute changes and if there is just replace the new values with the old ones like this:

```
var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;
            var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
                mutations.forEach(function(mutationRecord) {
                    mutationRecord.target.style.cssText = mutationRecord.oldValue
                });
            });

            observer.observe(elem, { attributes : true, attributeOldValue : true, attributeFilter : ['style'] });
```

But this code causes the browser to freeze.

all i want is to protect my iframe style from any changes.

Comment: The observer is triggered on any assignment even if the value is unchanged. You need to check if the current value is different and change it only in that case.

Comment: I tried that but the "mutationRecord.target.style.cssTex" contains the entire style attribute and for some reason it doesn't work...
can you give me a working example please?

Comment: Use the standard string manipulation techniques.

Comment: i have tried so many ways but i'm keep failing , can you please give me an example for this? i just need the observer to change the style to the old value if the style changes